# Trying to work with a WSL Ubuntu in order to use ROS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, path

So I've been trying to use the WSL ubuntu app so that I can use this ROS, but I don't exactly understand what I've been doing wrong. I was trying to use this command line:

```
$ catkin_make
```

but then it would say that I have some sort of an import error, which I cannot, for the love of god, get even the slightest idea on how to solve:

```
Base path: /home/thickmelon/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/thickmelon/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/thickmelon/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/thickmelon/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/thickmelon/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/thickmelon/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/thickmelon/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/melodic
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/melodic
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found suitable version "3.6.8", minimum required is "2")
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python3
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/thickmelon/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gmock will be built
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found version "3.6.8")
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
ImportError: "from catkin_pkg.package import parse_package" failed: No module named 'catkin_pkg'
Make sure that you have installed "catkin_pkg", it is up to date and on the PYTHONPATH.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  execute_process(/usr/bin/python3
  "/opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/parse_package_xml.py"
  "/opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/../package.xml"
  "/home/thickmelon/catkin_ws/build/catkin/catkin_generated/version/package.cmake")
  returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package_xml.cmake:74 (safe_execute_process)
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:167 (_catkin_package_xml)
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:56 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/thickmelon/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/thickmelon/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:320: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

and entering this command line:

```
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src
```

would yield this result:

```
bash: cd: /root/catkin_ws/src: No such file or directory
```

though I couldn't even find this so called directory "directory" in any of my folders on my computer, which is just so baffling to me.

Do I need to install something else? or should I just make a new folder named src in this directory that the prompt keeps talking about?

Comment: Please add some information about the setup. Like what repository are you trying to compile? What is the Windows 10 and Ubuntu version? Did you follow any instruction or guide?

Comment: I'm just trying to set up an environment (I guess? I'm not too familiar with the lingo) for a lidar sensor from this Chinese company. I've been following the instruction manual (a docx file) that the retailer gave us, which is included in this zip file that the following link will provide: https://www.devicemart.co.kr/goods/download?id=12170775&rank=1

Also, could you specify what you meant by "What is the Windows 10 and Ubuntu version?" please?